# Nginx server not automatically serving index.html files in subfolders

Tags: nginx

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

**PHYSICAL PATH:**  /subfolder/index.html

**URL TYPED BY USER:**  site.com/subfolder

**OUTPUT:** whatever the contents of /subfolder/index.html are.

I read that this should work automatically, but evidently it doesn't work on Nginx. (I've tested it on Apache, and it works there automatically.)

What is the best way to replicate this behaviour? Do I need to use rewrites, or can I make a simple change in a configuration file?

**EDIT:** [Here is a link to a copy of my configuration file.](http://pastebin.com/Sb9yyunR)
I know that it has index mentioned twice, and that the try_files section is a bit weird. Both those things came from my experimentation with different settings.

Comment: "I have a site which I run as a hobby using Nginx" – Better don't mention something like that when asking on serverfault... 8-)

Comment: I will keep that in mind.

Comment: What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: It doesn't automatically serve an index.html file if you request its enclosing folder. I discovered I had a section in my config that automatically redirected you to the main page if you didn't type the exact url. After I removed that, it worked as expected.

Comment: OK. But please put answers in an Answer, not in the Question.

Comment: I wanted to give @Dennis Kaarsemaker a chance to create an answer, because it was his comment that lead me to this solution, so I put the answer in the question as a temporary measure until he creates an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to remove the following lines from my config.

```
if (!-f $request_filename) {
    rewrite ^ /index.html last;    
}
```

Thanks to @Dennis Kaarsemaker who suggested deleting lines from my config to see what the problem was.

Comment: @Dennis Kaarsemaker, if you want to make your own answer, I'll accept it instead, and delete this one.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing an `index` statement:

```
server {
    ...

    location / {
        ...
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

Comment: That didn't fix it. (I already had that line in the server section, but adding it to the location section had no effect.) [Here is a link to my config file.](http://pastebin.com/Sb9yyunR)

Comment: Try without lines 8-15. If that works, add lines back until it breaks again. Then you know what's broken :)

Comment: That worked. The offending lines were   if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        rewrite ^ /index.html last;}

Comment: I'm not quite sure what the etiquette is here. Should I create an answer stating that the removal of the rewrite fixed it, or should I let you create an answer stating the same thing so I can accept it?

Comment: That line made Nginx check if the exact file existed, and if not, redirected to the main page. I suspect the same functionality could be better implemented using try_files.